# Upgradation from oracle 12c to oracle 19c resulting in degradation in performance of Query

Tags: java, oracle

I have moved from Oracle 12c to Oracle 19c. There is major degradation observed in select queries. I'm executing the select query for 50k - 1L records but it takes almost double-time than Oracle 12c. The same issue is observed even while fetching 500 records.

```
select * from TABLE_NAME where ((col1='1' and col2='1' and col3='1' and col4='SAT, JUL 31 2021 00:00:00 GMT') or (col1='1' and col2='1' and col3='1' and col4='SAT, JUL 31 2021 00:00:00 GMT').........);
```

The above 4 columns passed in the query are unique keys of the table.

I tried setting optimizer_features_enable('12.1.0.2'), it didn't give me improvement.

Can anyone please help me out ?

The query execution plan for Oracle 12 is as follows :

```
{
      "version": "1",
      "signature": "Oracle JDBC driver",
      "date": "2021-08-03T11:54:18.642048800",
      "sql": "\r\nselect\r\n       \r\n        this_.col1 as RDPD0_0_,\r\n        this_.col2 as col2_,\r\n        this_.col5 as Transfer5_0_0_,\r\n        this_.col6 as ProductN6_0_0_,\r\n        this_.RDPD1 as RDPD7_0_0_,\r\n        this_.RMPD as RMPD0_0_,\r\n        this_.RDPD3 as RDPD10_0_0_,\r\n        this_.RDPD2 as RDPD11_0_0_,\r\n       ,\r\n        this_.RMP as RMP0_0_,\r\n ,\r\n    ,\r\n       ,\r\n  this_.RDP as RDP0_0_,\r\n        this_.col1 as Product20_0_0_,\r\n        this_.col3 as RetailZ21_0_0_,\r\n        this_.col4 as Effecti22_0_0_,\r\n        this_.col2 as col20_0_ \r\n    from\r\n        TABLE_NAME this_ \r\n    where\r\n        (\r\n            (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n\t\t\t\t) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n\t\t\t or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n\t\t\t or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ))\r\n",
      "root": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "kind": "Node",
          "type": "SELECT STATEMENT",
          "cond": "",
          "desc": "",
          "attributes": [
            {
              "statement_id": "krvoebs9lcntv4"
            },
            {
              "plan_id": 33
            },
            {
              "timestamp": 1627971863000
            },
            {
              "remarks": ""
            },
            {
              "operation": "SELECT STATEMENT"
            },
            {
              "options": ""
            },
            {
              "object_node": ""
            },
            {
              "object_owner": ""
            },
            {
              "object_name": ""
            },
            {
              "object_alias": ""
            },
            {
              "object_instance": 0
            },
            {
              "object_type": ""
            },
            {
              "optimizer": "ALL_ROWS"
            },
            {
              "search_columns": 0
            },
            {
              "id": 0
            },
            {
              "depth": 0
            },
            {
              "position": 550
            },
            {
              "cost": 550
            },
            {
              "cardinality": 1
            },
            {
              "bytes": 143
            },
            {
              "other_tag": ""
            },
            {
              "partition_start": ""
            },
            {
              "partition_stop": ""
            },
            {
              "partition_id": 0
            },
            {
              "other": ""
            },
            {
              "distribution": ""
            },
            {
              "cpu_cost": 86299946
            },
            {
              "io_cost": 545
            },
            {
              "temp_space": 0
            },
            {
              "access_predicates": ""
            },
            {
              "filter_predicates": ""
            },
            {
              "projection": ""
            },
            {
              "time": 1
            },
            {
              "qblock_name": ""
            },
            {
              "other_xml": ""
            },
            {
              "parent_id": 0
            }
          ],
          "child": [
            {
              "name": "TABLE_NAME",
              "kind": "Node",
              "type": "TABLE ACCESS",
              "cond": "",
              "desc": "",
              "attributes": [
                {
                  "statement_id": "krvoebs9lcntv4"
                },
                {
                  "plan_id": 33
                },
                {
                  "timestamp": 1627971863000
                },
                {
                  "remarks": ""
                },
                {
                  "operation": "TABLE ACCESS (FULL)"
                },
                {
                  "options": "FULL"
                },
                {
                  "object_node": ""
                },
                {
                  "object_owner": "ORA12_01"
                },
                {
                  "object_name": "TABLE_NAME"
                },
                {
                  "object_alias": "THIS_@SEL$1"
                },
                {
                  "object_instance": 1
                },
                {
                  "object_type": "TABLE"
                },
                {
                  "optimizer": "ANALYZED"
                },
                {
                  "search_columns": 0
                },
                {
                  "id": 1
                },
                {
                  "depth": 1
                },
                {
                  "position": 1
                },
                {
                  "cost": 550
                },
                {
                  "cardinality": 1
                },
                {
                  "bytes": 143
                },
                {
                  "other_tag": ""
                },
                {
                  "partition_start": ""
                },
                {
                  "partition_stop": ""
                },
                {
                  "partition_id": 0
                },
                {
                  "other": ""
                },
                {
                  "distribution": ""
                },
                {
                  "cpu_cost": 86299946
                },
                {
                  "io_cost": 545
                },
                {
                  "temp_space": 0
                },
                {
                  "access_predicates": ""
                },
                {
                  "filter_predicates": "TO_NUMBER(\"THIS_\".\"col2\")\u003d1 AND TO_NUMBER(\"THIS_\".\"col3\")\u003d1 AND TO_NUMBER(\"THIS_\".\"col1\")\u003d1 AND \"THIS_\".\"col4\"\u003dTO_TIMESTAMP(\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027)"
                },
                {
                  "projection": "\"THIS_\".\"col1\"[NUMBER,22], \"THIS_\".\"RDPD\"[NUMBER,22], \"THIS_\".\"col6\"[VARCHAR2,400], \"THIS_\".\"col1\"[VARCHAR2,400], \"THIS_\".\"col2\"[VARCHAR2,400], \"THIS_\".\"col2\"[VARCHAR2,400], \"THIS_\".\"RDPD1\"[NUMBER,22], \"THIS_\".\"RMPD\"[NUMBER,22],\"THIS_\".\"RDPD3\"[NUMBER,22], \"THIS_\".\"RDPD2\"[NUMBER,22], \"THIS_\".\"RMP\"[NUMBER,22], \"THIS_\".\"col5\"[NUMBER,22], \"THIS_\".\"col3\"[VARCHAR2,400], \"THIS_\".\"DATEMODIFIED\"[TIMESTAMP,11], \"THIS_\".\"col4\"[TIMESTAMP,11], \"THIS_\".\"RDP\"[NUMBER,22]"
                },
                {
                  "time": 1
                },
                {
                  "qblock_name": "SEL$1"
                },
                {
                  "other_xml": "\u003cother_xml\u003e\u003cinfo type\u003d\"db_version\"\u003e12.1.0.2\u003c/info\u003e\u003cinfo type\u003d\"parse_schema\"\u003e\u003c![CDATA[\"ORA12_01\"]]\u003e\u003c/info\u003e\u003cinfo type\u003d\"plan_hash_full\"\u003e187850946\u003c/info\u003e\u003cinfo type\u003d\"plan_hash\"\u003e2346669158\u003c/info\u003e\u003cinfo type\u003d\"plan_hash_2\"\u003e187850946\u003c/info\u003e\u003coutline_data\u003e\u003chint\u003e\u003c![CDATA[FULL(@\"SEL$1\" \"THIS_\"@\"SEL$1\")]]\u003e\u003c/hint\u003e\u003chint\u003e\u003c![CDATA[OUTLINE_LEAF(@\"SEL$1\")]]\u003e\u003c/hint\u003e\u003chint\u003e\u003c![CDATA[ALL_ROWS]]\u003e\u003c/hint\u003e\u003chint\u003e\u003c![CDATA[DB_VERSION(\u002712.1.0.2\u0027)]]\u003e\u003c/hint\u003e\u003chint\u003e\u003c![CDATA[OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE(\u002712.1.0.2\u0027)]]\u003e\u003c/hint\u003e\u003chint\u003e\u003c![CDATA[IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS]]\u003e\u003c/hint\u003e\u003c/outline_data\u003e\u003c/other_xml\u003e"
                },
                {
                  "parent_id": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

The query execution plan for Oracle 19c is as follows :

```
{
  "version": "1",
  "signature": "Oracle JDBC driver",
  "date": "2021-08-02T18:58:29.743771600",
  "sql": "select\r\n        this_.col1 as col10_0_, \r\n        this_.RDPD as RDPD0_0_,\r\n        this_.col2 as col2_, \r\n        this_.col6 as ProductN6_0_0_,\r\n        this_.RDPD1 as RDPD7_0_0_,\r\n        this_.RMPD as RMPD0_0_,\r\n        this_.RDPD3 as RDPD10_0_0_,\r\n        this_.RDPD2 as RDPD11_0_0_,\r\n       ,\r\n        this_.RMP as RMP0_0_,\r\n        \r\n        ,\r\n        ,\r\n       ,\r\n        ,\r\n        this_.RDP as RDP0_0_,\r\n        this_.col1 as Product20_0_0_,\r\n        this_.col3 as RetailZ21_0_0_,\r\n        this_.col4 as Effecti22_0_0_,\r\n        this_.col2 as col20_0_ \r\n    from\r\n        TABLE_NAME this_ \r\n    where\r\n        (\r\n            (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n\t\t\t\t) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n            or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n\t\t\t or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ) \r\n\t\t\t or (\r\n                this_.col1\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col3\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col2\u003d1 \r\n                and this_.col4\u003d\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027\r\n            ))",
  "root": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "kind": "Node",
      "type": "SELECT STATEMENT",
      "cond": "",
      "desc": "",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "statement_id": "kruo2pkopof6w4"
        },
        {
          "plan_id": 15
        },
        {
          "timestamp": 1627910826000
        },
        {
          "remarks": ""
        },
        {
          "operation": "SELECT STATEMENT"
        },
        {
          "options": ""
        },
        {
          "object_node": ""
        },
        {
          "object_owner": ""
        },
        {
          "object_name": ""
        },
        {
          "object_alias": ""
        },
        {
          "object_instance": 0
        },
        {
          "object_type": ""
        },
        {
          "optimizer": "ALL_ROWS"
        },
        {
          "search_columns": 0
        },
        {
          "id": 0
        },
        {
          "depth": 0
        },
        {
          "position": 546
        },
        {
          "cost": 546
        },
        {
          "cardinality": 1
        },
        {
          "bytes": 5411
        },
        {
          "other_tag": ""
        },
        {
          "partition_start": ""
        },
        {
          "partition_stop": ""
        },
        {
          "partition_id": 0
        },
        {
          "other": ""
        },
        {
          "distribution": ""
        },
        {
          "cpu_cost": 14359036
        },
        {
          "io_cost": 545
        },
        {
          "temp_space": 0
        },
        {
          "access_predicates": ""
        },
        {
          "filter_predicates": ""
        },
        {
          "projection": ""
        },
        {
          "time": 1
        },
        {
          "qblock_name": ""
        },
        {
          "other_xml": ""
        },
        {
          "parent_id": 0
        }
      ],
      "child": [
        {
          "name": "TABLE_NAME",
          "kind": "Node",
          "type": "TABLE ACCESS",
          "cond": "",
          "desc": "",
          "attributes": [
            {
              "statement_id": "kruo2pkopof6w4"
            },
            {
              "plan_id": 15
            },
            {
              "timestamp": 1627910826000
            },
            {
              "remarks": ""
            },
            {
              "operation": "TABLE ACCESS (FULL)"
            },
            {
              "options": "FULL"
            },
            {
              "object_node": ""
            },
            {
              "object_owner": "ORA19C_1"
            },
            {
              "object_name": "TABLE_NAME"
            },
            {
              "object_alias": "\"THIS_\"@\"SEL$1\""
            },
            {
              "object_instance": 1
            },
            {
              "object_type": "TABLE"
            },
            {
              "optimizer": ""
            },
            {
              "search_columns": 0
            },
            {
              "id": 1
            },
            {
              "depth": 1
            },
            {
              "position": 1
            },
            {
              "cost": 546
            },
            {
              "cardinality": 1
            },
            {
              "bytes": 5411
            },
            {
              "other_tag": ""
            },
            {
              "partition_start": ""
            },
            {
              "partition_stop": ""
            },
            {
              "partition_id": 0
            },
            {
              "other": ""
            },
            {
              "distribution": ""
            },
            {
              "cpu_cost": 14359036
            },
            {
              "io_cost": 545
            },
            {
              "temp_space": 0
            },
            {
              "access_predicates": ""
            },
            {
              "filter_predicates": "TO_NUMBER(\"THIS_\".\"col3\")\u003d1 AND TO_NUMBER(\"THIS_\".\"col2\")\u003d1 AND TO_NUMBER(\"THIS_\".\"col1\")\u003d1 AND \"THIS_\".\"col4\"\u003dTO_TIMESTAMP(\u0027THU, 29 JUL 2021 00:00:00 GMT\u0027)"
            },
            {
              "projection": "\"THIS_\".\"col1\"[NUMBER,22], \"THIS_\".\"col6\"[VARCHAR2,400], \"THIS_\".\"col1\"[VARCHAR2,400], \"THIS_\".\"col2\"[VARCHAR2,4]\"THIS_\".\"RDPD3\"[NUMBER,22], \"THIS_\".\"RDPD2\"[NUMBER,22], \"THIS_\".\"RMP\"[NUMBER,22],\"THIS_\".\"col3\"[VARCHAR2,400], \"THIS_\".\"col4\"[TIMESTAMP,11], \"THIS_\".\"RDP\"[NUMBER,22]"
            },
            {
              "time": 1
            },
            {
              "qblock_name": "SEL$1"
            },
            {
              "other_xml": "\u003cother_xml\u003e\u003cinfo type\u003d\"has_user_tab\"\u003eyes\u003c/info\u003e\u003cinfo type\u003d\"db_version\"\u003e19.0.0.0\u003c/info\u003e\u003cinfo type\u003d\"parse_schema\"\u003e\u003c![CDATA[\"ORA19C_1\"]]\u003e\u003c/info\u003e\u003cinfo type\u003d\"plan_hash_full\"\u003e187850946\u003c/info\u003e\u003cinfo type\u003d\"plan_hash\"\u003e2346669158\u003c/info\u003e\u003cinfo type\u003d\"plan_hash_2\"\u003e187850946\u003c/info\u003e\u003cstats type\u003d\"compilation\"\u003e\u003cstat name\u003d\"bg\"\u003e10\u003c/stat\u003e\u003c/stats\u003e\u003cqb_registry\u003e\u003cq o\u003d\"2\" f\u003d\"y\"\u003e\u003cn\u003e\u003c![CDATA[SEL$1]]\u003e\u003c/n\u003e\u003cf\u003e\u003ch\u003e\u003ct\u003e\u003c![CDATA[THIS_]]\u003e\u003c/t\u003e\u003cs\u003e\u003c![CDATA[SEL$1]]\u003e\u003c/s\u003e\u003c/h\u003e\u003c/f\u003e\u003c/q\u003e\u003c/qb_registry\u003e\u003coutline_data\u003e\u003chint\u003e\u003c![CDATA[FULL(@\"SEL$1\" \"THIS_\"@\"SEL$1\")]]\u003e\u003c/hint\u003e\u003chint\u003e\u003c![CDATA[OUTLINE_LEAF(@\"SEL$1\")]]\u003e\u003c/hint\u003e\u003chint\u003e\u003c![CDATA[ALL_ROWS]]\u003e\u003c/hint\u003e\u003chint\u003e\u003c![CDATA[DB_VERSION(\u002719.1.0\u0027)]]\u003e\u003c/hint\u003e\u003chint\u003e\u003c![CDATA[OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE(\u002719.1.0\u0027)]]\u003e\u003c/hint\u003e\u003chint\u003e\u003c![CDATA[IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS]]\u003e\u003c/hint\u003e\u003c/outline_data\u003e\u003c/other_xml\u003e"
            },
            {
              "parent_id": 0
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: how did you upgrade?

Comment: Explain plan used to be something legible. Is col4 a date? If so, compare it to a date, not a string.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have the original execution plan, it might be difficult to work what has changed, but perhaps at least see where the time has gone by doing

- exec dbms_monitor.session_trace_enable(waits=>true)
- run your query
- exec dbms_monitor.session_trace_disable

or just see if the optimizer is working with poor statistics (or making a poor decision) via running your query via

```
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ ...
from ...
```

(ie, the rest of your query) and then checking the actuals versus estimate with

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'ALLSTATS LAST'))
```

Alternatively (if you are licensed for it) you can do this via SQL Monitor. A video demo of that can be found [here](https://youtu.be/TAuxo0TyPzU)